# Correct way of using express middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have a question regarding express (connect) middleware.
What i'm trying to do is downloading DoubleClick Bid Manager Reports, parse and process them into my own MongoDB database.

My route looks as following:

```
    app.route('/v1/spends/')
    .get(dbmPolicy.isAllowed, buckets.read, buckets.check, reports.create, buckets.process, reports.update);
```

Where `buckets.read` reads files from Google Cloud Storage, `buckets.check` checks if report has already been processed into MongoDB, `reports.create` creates the report that holds the metadata of the csv. `buckets.process` processes the data that resides inside of the csv and `reports.update` updates the previously created report if all went succesfull.

As I find it very difficult to test the above process, I'm starting to doubt whether this is the correct way to implement the chain of processes. If this is the correct way, how do I test each middleware function individually on it's behaviour?

Regards,

Comment: I don't think middleware is what you're looking for. If each successive step requires data from the previous step you would need to use callbacks or promises. Middleware manages what happens between the request and the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into the [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) package and especially the [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) method. That way you can run something like:

```
app.get('/v1/spends', function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        dbmPolicy.isAllowed,
        buckets.read,
        buckets.check,
        reports.create,
        buckets.process,
        reports.update    
    ], function (err, result) {
       if (err) res.status(500).send(err); 
       res.status(200).send(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense!

Comment: I think the dbmPolicy, isAllowed should be outside of the waterfall, is it not?

Comment: It depends on what your logic does, but when I use a waterfall I try to keep everything within the realm of the function. If it is a conditional, you can just have it run the callback with an error and it will stop all the other functions from happening, so you can just add it to the waterfall stack and keep your code clean